# All routes work except for router.delete due to 'UnauthorizedError: Unauthorized'. Why?

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, express-jwt

I have a Vue project and all of my routes are structured the same, however, one of them always gives me an unauthorized error.

Here are the routes:

```
router.get('/:userId/reviews', checkJwt, verifyUser, controller.getReviewsByUserId)
router.put('/:userId/review', checkJwt, verifyUser, controller.updateReview)
router.delete('/:userId/review', checkJwt, verifyUser, controller.removeReviewFromUser) // this is the broken route
```

If I were to change the broken route to:

```
router.put('/:userId/delete/review', checkJwt, verifyUser, controller.removeReviewFromUser)
```

Then it works just fine. The `checkJwt` middleware is where the issue is coming from. But I have 10 other routes that are structured IDENTICALLY to the `delete` route that is failing. Why?

Here is the `checkJwt` code even though this should not be where the issue is since it DOES work for all of my other 15 routes as long as the http verb is `put`, `post`, or '`get`:

```
const { auth } = require('express-oauth2-jwt-bearer')

// Setup auth
const checkJwt = auth({
  audience: 'MY-AUDIENCE',
  issuerBaseURL: 'https://simplyadvanced.auth0.com/'
})

module.exports = {
  checkJwt
}
```

And here is the full error message:

```
UnauthorizedError: Unauthorized
    at getToken (C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express-oauth2-jwt-bearer\dist\index.js:83:15)
    at C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express-oauth2-jwt-bearer\dist\index.js:353:25
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:360:14)
    at param (C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:371:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\cody\App\app-core\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:416:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. DELETE requests should not have a request body so by removing the body and adding the ID to the URL request parameter, it worked.